# Prove set inclusion involving a symmetric difference

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Consider a mapping $f : S \rightarrow S$ and let $A \subset S$. Denote by $f^{-n}(A)$ the preimage of $A$ w.r.t. the $n$'th application of $f$. Set
$$
B := \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} f^{-n}(A) = \bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} f^{-k}(A).
$$

> I am interested in showing that
> $$
> A \triangle B \subset \bigcup_{k = 0}^\infty \left(f^{-k}(A) \triangle f^{-(k+1)}(A)\right),
> $$
> where $\triangle$ denotes the symmetric difference, i.e. $A \triangle B = (A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B) = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$.

We can observe that
$$
f^{-1}(B) = f^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} f^{-k}(A)\right) = \bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} f^{-1}(f^{-k}(A)) = \bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} f^{-(k+1)}(A) = \bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n+1}^{\infty} f^{-k}(A) = B.
$$
Can this be used to show the inclusion?